# Call my name and I will come home!

Tags: riddle, word

I can fit in all three visible dimensions, 3 times in reverse.
I am a deficiency of what I ought to be.
I can have one thing more in common with the one true way,
than to the ultimate key but both are widely accepted.
I can travel in packs, sometimes 'lone,
you could say somewhere in the Twilight Zone.

**Hint:**

> Some people think I'm kinky, some people call me tame! What is my name?

**day 2 hint**

> I matter according to the chemistry teacher

**day 3 hint**

> I am a Christian

**day 4 hint**

> Hi your name is a prefix and my grandsons is an anagram, of you look at me you also might notice some connection. Now go catch them all.

**day 5 hint**

> I'm also a Sascha ;)

**day 6 hint**

> Length times width, or not?

**day 7 hint**

> I'm not sure if your wife prefers scoring high on this balance or the the one measuring mass.

I would like to add a bonus hint even after solving:

> Bergamot made me royalty

Comment: Call my name -> say my name + my chemistry teacher ... starting to sound like *Heisenberg* to me...

Comment: @stackreader You are both correct and incorrect at the same time. *Call my name* does not reference him fyi.

Comment: Just throwing one more random Idea but.... the 4th hint "go catch them all." might be connected to pokemon, which would make the grandson gary and the grandpa oak.

Comment: @stackreader correct, now you are getting close

Comment: I'm sorry man I'm not getting any ideas. Remove my answer as the correct answer so probably more people will take a look at the riddle

Comment: @glugglug There are like 4 more sub-answers in the comments to find at this moment, you don't even have to think them up yourself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: This is a collation of answers from glugglug's answer and the ensuing comments, with some tweaks from me.

The answer is:

> Gray

Call my name and I'll come home!

> Adaption of lyric from I Don't Wanna Live Forever (ZAYN & Taylor Swift) from Fifty Shades Darker soundtrack.

I can fit in all three visible dimensions, 3 times in reverse.

> This may be a reference to RGB color mixing.

I am a deficiency of what I ought to be.

> Gray is a deficiency of black

I can have one thing more in common with the one true way,
than to the ultimate key but both are widely accepted.

> Gray can also be spelled grey. Both ‘gray’ and ‘grey’ have 3 letters in common with ‘the one true way’ but only 2 letters in common with ‘the ultimate key’.

I can travel in packs, sometimes 'lone,

> Gray wolf

you could say somewhere in the Twilight Zone.

> Twilight has various shades of gray

**Hints**

1. Some people think I'm kinky, some people call me tame! What is my name?

   > Christian Gray (50 Shades of Gray)
2. I matter according to the chemistry teacher

   > Gray matter - Breaking Bad episode
3. I am a Christian

   > Christian Gray (50 Shades of Gray)
4. Hi your name is a prefix and my grandsons is an anagram, of you look at me you also might notice some connection. Now go catch them all.

   > In this scenario, my name is Ash, which as a prefix gives ash-grey (a shade of grey). Gary is the grandson and Oak is the grandpa. Gary is an anagram of gray. Also the connection you find on looking is that professor Oak has grey hair.
5. I'm also a Sascha ;)

   > Sasha Grey
6. Length times width, or not?

   > Gray area
7. I'm not sure if your wife prefers scoring high on this balance or the the one measuring mass.

   > Gray scale
8. Bergamot made me royalty

   > Too easy - Earl Grey tea

Comment: Can you add something for the title (hint: current song) and for #4 the prefix part? #1 is correct: `3d => reverse = d3. Times 3 is` **d3d3d3**. I would like it if you also solve the latest hint, but you don't have to: I can answer that one myself.

Comment: P.S. #1 is more because of the assocation between 50 shades of grey and grey being also a bit of a dull color.

Answer (score 12):

You are:

> The letter 'e'

I can fit in all visible dimensions

> dim**e**nsions

3 times in reverse

> r**e**v**e**rs**e**

I am a deficiency of what I ought to be

> Not sure on this one.

I can have one thing more in common with the one true way, than to the ultimate key

> 3 es in "the one true way", 2 in "ultimate key"?

I can travel in packs, sometimes 'lone

> "beef" has a pack of e's in it.

you could say somewhere in the Twilight Zone

> There's an e in there

Comment: It's not my intended answer, but I like it as well :)

Comment: For the 'deficiency' line, I thought of 'vitamin' deficiency, because Vitamin E is a thing but there is no E in 'vitamin'.

Comment: No it's a completely different answer

Comment: If you include "the" in "the one true way", you probably also have to include it in "the ultimate key".

Comment: @AdamV yes, but if I did that, my obviously wrong answer would be even wronger, so I didn't :) It was a tough decision, but in the end I regret nothing.

Answer (score 7):

You are

> A dog

I can fit in all three visible dimensions, 3 times in reverse.

> dog in reverse is God, or [Father, Son and Holy Ghost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinity)

I am a deficiency of what I ought to be.

> You were a wolf

I can have one thing more in common with the one true way,
than to the ultimate key but both are widely accepted.

> Reference to the theory of evolution vs creationism? Still thinking this...

I can travel in packs, sometimes 'lone,

> A stray dog travels in packs, a tamed dog is usually alone

you could say somewhere in the Twilight Zone.

> [image]
>  Lonely, I am so lonely

Some people think I'm kinky, some people call me tame! What is my name?

> Oh, we all know kinky dogs. And tamed ones?

I matter according to the chemistry teacher

> Being with a dog release [oxytocine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxytocin), the love ormone

I am a Christian

> Uhm. Antoher reference to the dog - God pair?

Comment: Also fits the title very well. Nice one.

Comment: Haha nice but nope

Comment: Ps some of it is very close in some way!

Answer (score 5):

You are an:

> interference pattern of photons

I can fit in all visible dimensions:

> for example light scattering on horizontal/vertical/horizontal in the other direction slits

3 times in reverse:

> Inverse Fourier transformation, like holograms?

I am a deficiency of what I ought to be:

> A single particle can interfere with itself, so there should not be a particle to begin with

I can have one thing more in common with the one true way
than to the ultimate key but both are widely accepted:

> one true way: acting as a particle, ultimate key for interference is being a wave

I can travel in packs, sometimes 'lone:

> Photons are bosons, so they can occupy the same quantum-state

you could say somewhere in the Twilight Zone:

> In an interference pattern shadowy and lighted areas alternate, just like in a twilight.

Comment: I'm impressed by the scientific nature of your answer, but no that's not it

Answer (score 5):

I think you are

> The colour gray

1. I fit in all 3 dimensions

   > Colour can exist in all 3 dimensions
2. 3 times in reverse

   > Not sure about this one
3. I am a deficiency of what I ought to be.

   > Gray is black but deficient
4. I can have one thing more in common with the one true way,
   than to the ultimate key but both are widely accepted.

   > Not sure about this
5. I can travel in packs, sometimes 'lone,

   > There can be multiple shades of gray or just a single one
6. you could say somewhere in the Twilight Zone.

   > Twilight has various shads of gray
7. Some people think I'm kinky, some people call me tame! What is my name?

   > Not sure about this
8. I matter according to the chemistry teacher

   > Not sure about this
9. I am a Christian

   > Reference to christian gray in 50 shades of gray
10. Hi your name is a prefix and my grandsons is an anagram, of you look at me you also might notice some connection. Now go catch them all.

    > Credit to stack reader for this, Gary is the grandson and Oak is the grandpa. Gary is an anagram of gray. Also the connection you find on looking is that professor Oak has grey hair
11. I'm also a Sascha ;)

    > Sasha gray
12. Length times width, or not?

    > Not sure
13. I'm not sure if your wife prefers scoring high on this balance or the the one measuring mass

    > gray balance?

Comment: correct, but far from all clues are correct. If you number them, I will state which ones are correct.

Comment: Edited with numbers

Comment: 1 and 2 should be seen as 1 hint. 3, 6, 9 and 11 are correct.  10 is incomplete: you forgot about the prefix part. You could also try to explain the title.

Comment: in 10 I think he is talking to ash and therefore ash is a prefix / type of grey (ash gray)

Comment: for 8 , I think it is a reference to Gray, the unit of ionising radiation

Comment: no, check the comment under my question for the right direction

Comment: For 5. The gray wolf (pack & lone)  8. Gray matter - Breaking Bad episode per stack reader 12. Gray area

Comment: This question's bounty is still open, because many of the clues still have no answer

Comment: Shouldn't it be a Biology teacher instead of Chemistry teacher?

Comment: For 7, think "50 shades"

Comment: 13 is gray hair vs. weight, two problems that spouses stereotypically complain about to their partners.

Comment: @ArthurDent See Tom's comment

Comment: @KateGregory correct and the counterpart is that gray is a dull collar, hence tame

Comment: @Smurfy7777 Yes, the synonym is for balance is scale: greyscale vs a weighting scale

Comment: Oh, and of course 9 relates directly to 7 - the name of the "hero" of the book

Comment: @KateGregory This is because I liked the hint *I am a Christian* more: it has a double meaning. The title even references it tbh (spoiler) because I saw it was some fasion to relate it to a song on this site.

Comment: For 4, I think this refers to the differing spellings, gray/grey. Both are acceptable spellings, but gray is more common. "One true way" has three letters in common with the gray spelling, while "ultimate key" only has two.

Comment: @Irishpanda almost correct, the detail is about `grey` **not** rhyming with `key` although they end the same. `Way` does match in ending and in rhyme with `gray`.

Answer (score 4):

I think you're a

> Cross

I can fit in all three visible dimensions,

> Assuming you mean the axes that denote the 3 spatial dimensions, a cross can fit to look like the lines of two perpendicular axes.

3 times in reverse.

> Not really sure. But it could be something to do with a cross fitting to each of the XY, YZ and ZX planes.

I am a deficiency of what I ought to be.

> A 'cross' can also be an opposite to a 'tick'

Not sure about the first hint.

I matter according to the chemistry teacher

> Chemistry teachers tend to use 'X' as an unknown element in problems. It can also be used in reaction equations to denote certain element groups such as halogens.

I am a Christian

> A cross is synonymous to a crucifix.

Comment: I'm sorry but that's also not it

Answer (score 0):

<sup>As per my assumptions, I can match few hints with the answer.</sup>

---

The answer may be:

> Pizza

Call my name and I will come home!

> You can dial and order the Pizza, by home delivery it will reach you.

I can travel in packs, sometimes 'lone,

> Pizza will come by packs

**Hint:** Some people think I'm kinky, some people call me tame! What is my name?

> Some people saying Pizza is not got for health, the layers of Cheese flavored Pizzas are looks hairy.

Comment: No no no sorry :)